# Open an Outlook PST File Without Changing It

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a number of PST files created from MS Outlook 2013 on my local drive. I back these up to OneDrive. Whenever I open the PST files using Outlook OneDrive decides that they have been changed and backs up the whole file again.

How do I open the PST file for reading in Outlook without OneDrive backing up the whole file again?

Comment: What happens if you set the attribute of the *.pst files to read only?

Comment: I've often found this an annoyance myself. Setting read-only stops the files opening, at least with the pre-2013 Outlook versions I've used. There is a rather buggy freeware PST reader, which will open without updating the modification time, but I've abandoned it. The best solution I've found is to make a temporary copy and open that - slow, but nothing like as slow as an unnecessary back-up. An alternative is to suspend OneDrive, save the time-stamp using a port of the Unix `touch` utility, open the file, then after you've closed it restore the time-stamp, before resuming OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering options from commenters I came up with a different solution. I make two copies of my archive PST files. One copy I put on OneDrive and let it back it up. The other copy I put in a separate non-backed up location and open that with MS Outlook.

I just need to be careful never to modify my viewing copy without duplicating to the OneDrive copy. My personal workflow means that this is unlikely to happen for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. When opening PST file, Outlook changes it. I personally recommend you to backup your PST to MSG files. This way you can have them on OneDrive, you can browse them and open in Outlook without changing them.

Comment: Do you have any reference for how to do PST to MSG files you mention? Do you mean that I have one MSG file for each email, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep. One MSG for each email. This way everything will work reliably. You can find many tools to export/backup Outlook mailbox to MSG files including freeware.

Comment: If you want Microsoft solution, install windows live mail. When you have outlook open drag the emails to windows live mail. Once copied over, you can export them as msg files. A little roundabout way but may be less sketchy than third party software if you like Microsoft.